# adding values on array java

Tags: java, arrays

i don't know what's wrong. the array should be in Number or int.

here's my code:

```
Number[] freq;

    int place = 0;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("this.txt")));

    String read;

    String[] temp;

    int num;

    while((read = br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        temp = read.split(",");
        for(int i = 0; i<=temp.length; i++)
        {
            String t = temp[i];
            num = Integer.parseInt(t);
            freq[place] = num;
            place++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("done");
```

it shouldn't output some heavy result but i need it working.
i always get the error

```
variable freq might not have been initialized.
freq[place] = num;
```

Comment: Java arrays are not dynamic, you need to actually initialize them to a length of some sort before you use them.

Comment: the values that are going to be in that array aren't always in the same size. i know arrays must be first initialized with size but in this program it must be depended on how many are in the text file

Comment: Then you need to use another type of variable, such as an ArrayList, which can be dynamic in size.

Comment: can you show me on how it is on ArrayList?

Comment: (better to update your question if you have new information) dynamic sizing is a fairly common requirement, and there are usually better data structures than arrays. Have a look at [Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for examples

Comment: See my answer. As @jangroth said; it it best if you update the question with these new requirements.

Comment: sorry about that. i was searching about that then can't find answer like mine, decided to post the a question. i didn't notice at first that that make the title of this. btw, thanks everyone who answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a size for the Array. Since you indicated in the comments that it has to be dynamic, you'll have to instead use a different kind of variable that can be used with dynamic length, such as an ArrayList.

See this example:

```
// initialize an ArrayList:
List<Number> freq = new ArrayList<Number>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("this.txt")));

String read;
String[] temp;

int num;

while((read = br.readLine())!=null)
{
    temp = read.split(",");
    for(int i = 0; i<=temp.length; i++)
    {
        String t = temp[i];
        num = Integer.parseInt(t);
        freq.add( num );
    }

}

System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: nice it worked! thanks! now i know that List can be like that.

Answer (score 3):

You must initialise the array.

`Number[] freq = new Number[someSize]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an array size before you use an array in `JAVA`.

```
int[] someArray= new int[size]
```

Comment: There is no `Int` available in Java. You meant `int[size]`?